# Stop executing query when a condition evaluates to false (or true)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that stores basic information about files:

```
CREATE TABLE filez (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name   TEXT NOT NULL,
    size   BIGINT NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX filez__id__idx ON filez USING (id);
```

I need to select a set of files with combined size that does not exceed some THRESHOLD. The following is a trivialized query which achieves that (it could use the NON MATERIALIZED CTE syntax, but that is not important in this case):

```
SELECT id, name
FROM (
        SELECT id, name,
            SUM(size) OVER w AS total_size -- accumulating size of files
        FROM filez
        WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY id ASC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        ORDER BY id ASC
    ) AS t
WHERE total_size <= THRESHOLD
```

I have a personal  problem with this query: it goes over ALL records regardless whether the threshold was reached. I'd like the query to go over just the sufficient number of records (sorted by an indexed "id" field) and stop executing as soon as the threshold condition becomes false.

EDIT.

Maybe the problem of stopping a query could be generalized. If there was a function, let's call it `stop_query(BOOL):BOOL` which could prematurely end query execution based on arbitrary condition, as in the following example:

```
SELECT f1, f2
FROM tab1
WHERE stop_query(<some condition>)
```

alternatively

```
SELECT f1, f2
FROM tab1
WHERE CASE WHEN <some condition> THEN stop_query() ELSE TRUE END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html)-based [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WM270172)

```sql
create function filez_up_to_limit(p_limit numeric, p_cutoff_id int default 0) 
  returns table(id int,name text,size bigint)
language plpgsql as $f$
declare rc cursor for select * from filez 
                      where filez.id>p_cutoff_id 
                      order by filez.id;
        current_size int:=0;
begin
 open rc;
 while current_size<p_limit loop
   fetch rc into id,name,size;
   return next;
   current_size:=current_size+size;
 end loop;
end $f$;
```

```sql
explain analyze verbose 
select * from filez_up_to_limit(1e6);
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Function Scan on public.filez_up_to_limit (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=44) (actual time=6.680..6.791 rows=1978 loops=1) |
| Output: id, name, size |
| Function Call: filez_up_to_limit('1000000'::numeric, 0) |
| Planning Time: 0.037 ms |
| Execution Time: 6.961 ms |

```
explain analyze verbose 
select * from filez_up_to_limit(1e7);
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Function Scan on public.filez_up_to_limit (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=44) (actual time=38.977..40.305 rows=20111 loops=1) |
| Output: id, name, size |
| Function Call: filez_up_to_limit('10000000'::numeric, 0) |
| Planning Time: 0.020 ms |
| Execution Time: 41.382 ms |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WM270172)

Comment: Outside the box thinking! Although this non-SQL solution is not what I was originally looking for, it may be what I will end up doing 

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a "plain" SQL [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE), but it's uglier and slower even if you cheat. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nRGhf8FR):

```sql
explain analyze verbose 
with recursive cte as (
  (select fi.*,fi.size as sum_,1 n from filez fi order by id limit 1)
  union all
  (select fi.*,fi.size+cte.sum_,n+1 from cte,filez fi 
   where fi.size+cte.sum_<1e7
   and fi.id=(select min(id) from filez where id>cte.id))
)
select * from cte;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Planning Time: 0.181 ms |
| Execution Time: 302.663 ms |

By cheating I mean adding an assumption that ids are continuous, freeing you from having to always check the next one. It is rarely the case because of how [sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html#id-1.9.3.81.7) work.

```sql
explain analyze verbose
with recursive cte as (
  select fi.*,fi.size as sum_,2 n from filez fi where id=1
  union all
  select fi.*,fi.size+cte.sum_,n+1 from cte,filez fi where fi.id=cte.n
  and fi.size+cte.sum_<1e7
)
select * from cte;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Planning Time: 0.470 ms |
| Execution Time: 83.082 ms |